# mariadb: howto c-connect bindings

Tags: c, mariadb

I'm working with `mariadb` and `c-connect` prepared statements and run into crashes executing them once a while. I'm also aware [the documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connectorc-data-structures/#mysql_bind) about binding interface is pretty thin because of interests.

**I'm so looking for better understanding MYSQL_BIND structure.**
First of all binding parameters. I have do "describe" my buffer in order to enable the server to read it correctly. do I have to describe my c buffer or database buffer?
By example c support STRING but no VAR_STRING. What happens if I define STRING buffer and bind it to a datetime db field?

Well it works - great. but often it just crashes the process. It takes a lot of time to get knowledge by try and error.

This lead to my questions i'm after without success since over a year "where can i read more about:

- used binding mindset and rules?
- implicit conversions (date<>string, ..) integrated in c-connector?"

Bind documentation shows `is_nulll  Pointer which indicates if column is NULL (not used for parameters)` and `is_null_value Used if is_null pointer is NULL`.
Applying this information with `is_null_value   Used if is_null pointer is NULL` to your code you would bind a parameter string something alike:

```
bnd[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
bnd[0].buffer = (void*) para->name;
bnd[0].is_null_value = para->nameI; // 0 or 1
bnd[0].length = strlen (para->name);
```

This would be logic but never worked out until now for me. Did it for you? what I'm after is the answer for "What is the correct way to bind parameters as a ruleset and why?"

Have a great day

Answer (score 1):

`MYSQL_BIND` can be used for sending data (`mysql_stmt_bind_param()`) and for retrieving data (`mysql_stmt_bind_result()`).

**Sending data:**

When sending data you have to provide the address, type and length of a parameter, e.g.

```
bind[0].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
bind[0].buffer_length= strlen(para->name);
bind[0].buffer= &para->name;
```

additionally, if para->name might be NULL, then you have to specifiy

```
bind[0].is_null= &para->is_null; /* para->is_null can be 0 or 1 */
```

**Retrieving data:**

When retrieving data, you need to specify the maximum buffer size, type and buffer address:

```
bind[0].buffer_type= MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
bind[0].buffer_length= max_buffer_length;
bind[0].buffer= param->name;
```

Additionally you might want to know the length of the value and/or if the retrieved value is NULL.

```
bind[0].is_null= &param->is_null;
bind[0].length= &param->length;
```

Please note that both is_null and length are pointers.

After fetching data param->name should contain the data, param->length contains the actual length and param->is_null indicates if you retrieved a NULL value.

Comment: thank you for your answer. while digging for more information about binding structure i found [mariadb wiki](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/wiki/datastructures) which is connected to you. thank you for your work.  </br> please could you explain comment  not used for parameters in <my_bool * is_null Pointer which indicates if column is NULL (not used for parameters)>.  </br>does it mean setting it to any value never will change behavior of execute?